# How can I add a screen shake effect to a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-editing

I have a video I'm trying to make for a dumb joke. The input video stream could be anything, but in my case it's an image file that I'm adding audio to. I want to apply a screen shake effect/earthquake effect to the video to make it a bit more dramatic. Is there a simple way to do this with ffmpeg? I know ffmpeg can do a lot, but at a certain point it gets a bit impractical to do everything in ffmpeg.

Comment: Check out [this link](https://www.gariany.com/2020/08/ffmpeg-step-by-step-retro-video-filter/).

Comment: And [another implementation](https://zayne.io/articles/recreate-this-effect-with-ffmpeg). Both came from a same reddit post